# Gmapping file map output structure

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody! Where can I find the map 2d file structure of the output of mapserver (gmapping)?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166436/gmapping-file-map-output-structure/) by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gmapping publishes a /map topic, normally you would use the map_server package to save this topic to a file:

```
rosrun map_server map_saver
```

See the wiki page for other options http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0